# Tortoise SVN best dev/merge/release model for a complicated setup

Tags: merge, tortoisesvn, branch

Our dev team works inside existing projects, and deploys on completely separate environments.  The work we do is not never expected to be merged back into theirs, but we are required to stay in line with them.  They use the traditional trunk-branch (but not really tags) setup.  A branch is created for a production release, and then development continues **on it** as they release.

The way our team does it, we copy their release branches to our own trunk (initially), which itself contains trunk/branches/tags.  During development we are on trunk, and tagging for production releases.  When we update from their latest release, its often impossible to do a straight merge from that branch to our trunk.  It seems much cleaner and trouble-free to start with their branch, merge in our work, and eventually rename it to trunk.

All of a sudden I feel like a subversion dummy text generator...

Given the constraint that we can't change the other team's workflow, is there a better flow for us?  Let me know if I'm missing something in the explanation too.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two main principles:

- Vendor branches
- **Merge often**

Due to ignorance of rule 2 you get "Merge hell" as expected

For more reasonable workflow (read about Vendor branches in Net, it has a lot of information) you can

- Not just copy upstream branch to your trunk, but create vendor-branch (branch) in  **your** repo, link it with svn:externals to source branch (without fixing source-revision in URL, link to moveable HEAD)
- Copy branch to (empty) trunk
- Monitor commits into upstream repo (SVNMonitor, CommitMonitor) and on **every commit** to upstream branch **merge** your vendor-**branch with your trunk** (svn 1.6-1.7 will be better than older versions)

After finishing upstream brach and starting new you can or edit externals definition in old branch (for next branch URL) or delete branch completely and start new (deleting all from your trunk not needed, only merge from new branch content)

Comment: We do essentially have vendor branches, but we work out the merge on the branch.  As i understand the vendor branch model, you don't touch the actual branch, but bring it in to the dev line for modifications.

Comment: So how can i copy this branch as the new trunk, maintaining history as much as possible?

Comment: svn co... you can (TBT!) just rm all conent of trunk tree before copy